# Опустить контент через определенное время после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Ребята, нужна очень Ваша помощь, задача:
Опустить контент через 5 секунд после загрузки страницы, если мы находимся в нулевой точке, сделать это нужно один раз. 
Мое решение - но оно не полное - буду рад если мне помогут:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 1){
            $('body').delay(1000).animate({
            scrollTop: 300
        }, 1700);
            return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @AlexSpike, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: проверить что мы в нулевой точке, setTimeout на 5 секунд, проверить что все ещё в нулевой точке, сместить. в чем проблема ? только что у вас за издевательство надо пользователем ?

Comment: А как правильно проверить, что мы в нулевой точке?